# How to make a Jquery menu builder

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui

I am developing a simple website for a client using Rails and I want to give them an easy way to create and manage their top navigation menu. Wordpress has a great tool (see example below) for this but I haven't found anything like it that is generally available.

So far I am thinking that [Jquery Sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/) would be the best place to start but to make it handle nested data (like trees), adding and removing elements, and add rules such as limiting the depth of nested elements seems like a lot of work.

How have you guys gone about solving this problem?

[image: Worderpress Style builder]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried [this](http://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/)

You can initialize like

```
$(function  () {
    $("ol").sortable()
})
```

It also supports animation.

You can also take a look into the [alternatives](http://johnny.github.io/jquery-sortable/#alternatives) provided

Comment: yes it does support. jQuery UI doesn't have that functionality but the plugin which i have provided has that functionality. Click the link and checkout their demo.